# GO Multiple Pointers

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a function that receives multiple types of struct and add those pointer values to another function.

> Example:

```go
type Model1 struct {
  Name string
}

type Model2 struct {
  Type bool
}

func MyFunc(value ...interface{}) {
  OtherFunc(value...)
}

func main() {
  MyFunc( new(Model), new(Mode2) );
}
```

The problem is that `OtherFunc` only allow `&value, &value, etc` as parameter. Have some way to pass those values like `OtherFunc(&value...)`?

Comment: What is the signature of `OtherFunc`? is it `OtherFunc(values ...inteface{})` or something else?

Comment: I'm using **gorm** and the signature is `func (s *DB) AutoMigrate(values ...interface{}) *DB`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this will solve your problem entirely however, the exact thing you requested is a feature in the language. You just have to use composite-literal syntax for instantiation instead of new. So you could do this to pass pointers; `MyFunc( &Model{}, &Mode2{} )`

Thing is, you're still going to be dealing with an `interface{}` within `MyFunc` so I'm not sure that will just be able to call `OtherFunc` without some unboxing (would probably be a type assertion if you want to get technical).